# How to report participant number with missing times?

Tags: mixed-model, missing-data, reporting

I have used a linear mixed model for a set of data with children participating in experiments 1-4 times. The number of times they participated varies. Some kids skipped or participated in one or two experiments, etc. We want to use the data as much as possible because it is quite hard to access these kids. How should I report the number of participants in a report? Is there a standard way to do it?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you say more? Is there an intervention?  Why are participants completing the survey twice, is it actually a longitudinal design, or are they doing it twice in a row to try and get a second gift card? Is this the AddHealth dataset?

Answer (score 1):

In study design, you need to define analysis sets. Traditionally, one defines intent to treat (ITT) and per protocol (PP) populations. Suppose you're assessing depression, i.e. proportion of patients improving symptoms on the CES-D. The ITT population is everyone who consents to participate but the PP requires they complete at least one post-baseline survey questionnaire. If only half of the sample actually completes a post-baseline questionnaire, but all of them show improvement of symptoms, your primary endpoint is 100% improvement in the PP analysis set but only 50% in the ITT analysis set. They are different "N"s and fundamentally address different hypotheses.

In ITT analysis, you might be concerned if large amounts of missing data fail to show the true pessimism of the effect. In that case, you can use predictive models to try and estimate how much the trend "falls off the deep end" for non-responders using last-observation-carried-forward (LOCF), worst-observation-carried-forward (WOCF), or more detailed probability models. These are a kind of secondary or sensitivity analysis.